# Codio: command not found

Tags: bash, gruntjs, codio

It's my first time playing with Codio.

I cloned https://github.com/divshot/polymer-firebase-qa into a new project. Then I followed the readme and did

```
npm install && bower install
```

which finished with no errors.

Continuing, I did

```
grunt serve
```

which said

```
-bash: grunt: command not found
```

...
I know `grunt` is there because it ran as part of the bower install.
I have tried to install grunt on the cli (codio doesn't allow me), tried "Install Software" (it's not in the list), and tried googling to no avail.

Comment: What does `which grunt` output ?

Comment: `which grunt` outputs nothing (just a new terminal line)

Comment: Probably you need to specify the path of `grunt` (it does not exist in System path right now)

Comment: I believe `which grunt` or `type grunt` will return nothing, because it's not in your path. See where it is located. Use [`find`](http://man.he.net/?section=all&topic=find) command if required. Set [PATH](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/26047/how-to-correctly-add-a-path-to-path) [variable](http://www.wikihow.com/Change-the-Path-Variable-in-Linux) accordingly...